# Is it possible to send/recieve Message via GSM Modem in Java?

Tags: java, sms, serial-port, modem

Using RXTX library im doing serial communication.I want to do it in swing based application

1. Write an AT commands to read received SMS in GSM modem
2. I need to send the messages to mobiles from java application
   Is there any Java API which send/receive SMS using RxTx libraries.

Comment: Im getting **+CMS ERROR: 518** while im trying to communicate through the Hyperterminal"AT
OK
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGS=+91994435474
+CMS ERROR: 518"

Comment: That's not how you use AT+CGMS. Have you read the AT command specification?

Comment: Im using AT+CMGS to send a message.It's correct only know

Comment: Sorry, I typoed CGMS instead of CMGS in my comment. CMS Error 518 is "invalid parameter". You need the number enclosed in quotes like `AT+CMGS="+91994435474"`

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java API called [smslib](http://smslib.org).